# Static HttpClient needs a URI from app.settings

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, httpclient

I have a situation like the code below. How do I get the proxy URI from app.settings given that I can't inject IConfiguration or IOptions because the static HttpClient property already exists when the instantation of the class occurs?

```
public class SomeApiClient : ISomeApiClient
{
    private static readonly HttpClientHandler ProxyClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        Proxy = new WebProxy("http://serviceproxy.com"), //TODO Fetch from settings
        UseProxy = true,
    };

    //HttpClient is disposable but should be used liked this
    //(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/#how-to-fix-improper-instantiation-antipattern)
    private static readonly HttpClient RestClient = new HttpClient(ProxyClientHandler);

    //The rest of the non-static class goes here...
}
```

Comment: ProxyClientHandler.Proxy has a setter why not change in Constructor?

Comment: Maybe have a look at : [How to use Typed Clients with IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-ihttpclientfactory)

Comment: Setting the Proxy property in the constructor does work but I think that 'Typed Clients' is what I was looking for. Thank you both very much for your replies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the implementation ended up something like this:

```
        private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHttpClient<IApiClient, ApiClient>().ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
                {
                    var serviceProxy = new ServiceProxy();
                    hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("ServiceProxy").Bind(serviceProxy);

                    var handler = new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        Proxy = new WebProxy(serviceProxy.Uri),
                        UseProxy = true,
                    };

                    return handler;
                });
                services.AddOptions();
                services.Configure<PollingIntervals>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("PollingIntervals"));
                services.AddHostedService<DownloadWorker>();
                services.AddHostedService<ArchiveWorker>();

                ConfigureDependencyInjection(services);
            });
```

And the 'typed client' something like this:

```
public class ApiClient : IApiClient
{
    private readonly IConfiguration config;
    private readonly ILogger<ApiClient> logger;
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;


    public ApiClient(
        HttpClient httpClient,
        IConfiguration config,
        ILogger<ApiClient> logger)
    {
        this.config = config;
        this.logger = logger;
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        this.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        this.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    }
```

Interestingly, I'm now getting a load of logging about the actual HTTP requests that I wasn't getting before. I added logging filters to tune that:

```
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                //Added these filters to stop seeing too many details about Http requests/responses
                logging.AddFilter("System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IApiClient.ClientHandler", LogLevel.Warning);
                logging.AddFilter("System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IApiClient.LogicalHandler", LogLevel.Warning);
            });
```